# InputTagHelper validation attributes not generated after 1st iteration of loop

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When using the InputTagHelper in a loop on a Razor Page (AspNetCore 2.2.0 NuGet packages) I am finding that the data-val-* attributes are only being generated on the first iteration.

The example below shows a basic model where two properties have the [Required] data annotation. The Razor Page iterates over the collection and renders the markup using a Partial Page.

Why does the output only have the data-val-* attributes for the first iteration and not the second?

How do I overcome this and have the InputTagHelper generate the attributes?

**Page**

```
<form>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tests.Count; i++)
    {
        <partial name="_Test" model="Model.Tests[i]" />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**Partial**

```
@model TestModel.Test
<div>
    <input asp-for="Index" id="Tests[@Model.Index]_Index" name="Tests[@Model.Index].Index" />
    <input asp-for="Id" id="Tests[@Model.Index]_Id" name="Tests[@Model.Index].Id" />
    <input asp-for="Name" id="Tests[@Model.Index]_Name" name="Tests[@Model.Index].Name" />
</div>
```

**PageModel**

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Tests = new List<Test>
        {
            new Test { Index = 0 },
            new Test { Index = 1 }
        };
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
<form novalidate="novalidate">
    <div>
        <input id="Tests[0]_Index" name="Tests[0].Index" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Index field is required." value="0">
        <input id="Tests[0]_Id" name="Tests[0].Id" type="number" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." value="">
        <input id="Tests[0]_Name" name="Tests[0].Name" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="Tests[1]_Index" name="Tests[1].Index" type="number" value="1">
        <input id="Tests[1]_Id" name="Tests[1].Id" type="number" value="">
        <input id="Tests[1]_Name" name="Tests[1].Name" type="text" value="">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to use `Model.Index`, but what's being iterated is `i` outside the partial. What you should be using here, actually, is the `for` attribute of the `PartialTagHelper`:

```
<form>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tests.Count; i++)
    {
        <partial name="_Test" for="Tests[i]" />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Then, in your partial:

```
@model TestModel.Test
<div>
    <input asp-for="Index" />
    <input asp-for="Id" />
    <input asp-for="Name" />
</div>
```